# How to remove main list items' anchor using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a list going like the following:

```
<div id="menuContainer">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#1">Main Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Main Item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#21">Sub Item 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#22">Sub Item 2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#22">Sub Item 2.3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#3">Main Item 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#31">Sub Item 3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#32">Sub Item 3.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to remove `<a>` tags of "Main Items" only.

I have tried to use

```
$('#menuContainer > ul > li > a').replaceWith($('#menuContainer > ul > li > a').text());
```

But it's removed all the anchors including sub items. I want script to do it for the first level items only, not deeper ones.

Comment: the `> ul` is unnecessary, since `#menu` itself is the first `ul`. Try `#menu > li > a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide `replaceWith` with a function which provides the `this` keyword to use as the reference for the current `a` element. You can then return the `text()` of the element to make the replacement.

```
$('#menuContainer > ul > li > a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8u3ppds6/)

Comment: Oops! I have put my code wrong. But your answer has given me basic idea. I think it would be nice if you update your answer according to my updated code for those who will encounter the same problem.